# VB Httpwebresponse get content

Tags: vb.net, httpwebresponse

On the following webpage I'd like to get all the titles of youtube videos in my listbox1

```
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest = webRequest.Create("https://www.youtube.com/results?q=test")
        Dim webresponse As WebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()

        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim youtube As String = sr.ReadToEnd

        Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("title="".*""")
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(youtube)

        For Each itemcode As Match In matches

            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(1))
```

However with this code I get the titles but also a bunch of other stuff...

Comment: Your code is incomplete... also be great if you show us the "other stuff".

Comment: YouTube have an API which you can use to search for videos and get the titles and other information without having to scrape a HTML page. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: @theduck Great, will take a look at that!

Comment: This is the specific call you want: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list. You will need to create yourself an API key using the Google console but then you can make the following call: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=test&key={YOUR_API_KEY} and you will get nicely formatted JSON as a result.

Comment: @theduck Thanks for all your input. Working with API requires C#?

Comment: There is a client library for c# that makes using the API easier but is not required. You can just call the API direct in vb.net and use the returned JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube provides an [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) which might be a better way to get this information. The specific call you want to make is documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list.

In order to use the YouTube API you will need to create an API key. This can be done from the [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com). Once you have a key then you can make calls to YouTube to search videos, get video information etc

Using your code as the basis you could use something along these lines:

```
Dim url As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=test&maxResults=50&key={YOUR-API-KEY}"

Dim webRequest As WebRequest = webRequest.Create(url)
Dim webresponse As WebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())

Dim youtube As String = sr.ReadToEnd

Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""title"": "".*""")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(youtube)

For Each itemcode As Match In matches
    ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1).Trim().TrimStart("""").TrimEnd(""""))
Next
```

The `q` parameter specifies the search query. This will get the first 50 matches to your search and put them in your drop down list.

Comment: Awesome mate, it's working but getting the results in quotes. Thanks for your help man :)

Comment: I have a hard time getting the results with " ". Could you maybe help again? Appreciated very much.

Comment: Is the problem with titles that contains quotes " in them? Eg. Say "hello"

Comment: Yes like that, titles will come like "Youtube video title" in my listbox.

Comment: OK - have updated code to handle this (if I have understood correctly). Ideally, you would deal with the JSON returned with a JSON parser rather than Regex but this will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with regular expression try the following

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("title=""([^""]*)""")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(youtube)


For Each itemcode As Match In matches
    ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Groups(1))
Next
```

However a dedicated API is cleaner

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this gives me the same results.

Comment: So you get more titles than you want?

Comment: I'm getting the titles but also other unwanted stuff.

Comment: However stuff that is inside a title="" string but that is not really a video title. Just to understand

Comment: I did not doubt that you have understood, I was just wondering about the meaning of "other stuff". When I pasted your code I got a lot of text probably due to the fact that regular expresion .* matches also double quote char. I was thinking you were trying to restrict the match